# Why does EC2 instance have problems upgrading my Ubuntu server to 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, upgrade

I just tried upgrading our Ubuntu EC2 server to 12.04 from 11.10, and it halts on several package upgrades, starting with memtest86+. CTRL+C is the only way out, and in the end there is the following error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 memtest86+
 ubuntu-standard
 grub-legacy-ec2
 grub-pc
 friendly-recovery
 linux-image-3.2.0-24-virtual
 python-apport
 linux-image-virtual
 linux-virtual
 apport
```

Any advice on what went wrong and how to fix it?

UPDATE: Turns out to be a problem with GRUB, though I still don't understand what is going wrong.  Why is GRUB used with EC2 at all?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error message?

Comment: there is no other error message, it just freezes at "Setting up memtest86+ (4.20-1.1ubuntu1) ..."

Comment: What release are you starting with?  What AMI id are you using as a base?

Comment: 11.10 to 12.04 LTS worked for me, via SSH connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try the upgrade again, but this time open a second ssh session to the server, and monitor some metrics:

- `vmstat 5` will alert you to memory problems
- `iostat 5` will show you if there is any I/O happening
- `top` will show you any problems with CPU spikes or load average
- using the `sysstat` package, you can log many of these metrics and view them later

Find out if anything is happening. View the list of running processes in `top` or `ps auxfw` for clues. Check active network connections with `netstat -utnp`. Once you have this info post back anything unusual or anything you don't understand.